# jQuery insert <br/> into text within a list item

Tags: jquery, insert, line-breaks, break

I have a list of items with varying string length:

```
<li class="rtsLI">
<a class="rtsLink rtsAfter" title="Something">
<span class="rtsOut">
<span class="rtsIn">
<span class="rtsTxt">
Short list item here</span>
</span>
</span>
</a>

</li>
<li class="rtsLI">
<a class="rtsLink rtsAfter" title="Something Else">
<span class="rtsOut">
<span class="rtsIn">
<span class="rtsTxt">
Really really really long list item goes here drop this text below</span>
</span>
</span>
</a>

</li>
<li class="rtsLI">
<a class="rtsLink rtsAfter" title="Something Else As well">
<span class="rtsOut">
<span class="rtsIn">
<span class="rtsTxt">
I might want to add a line here drop this text below</span>
</span>
</span>
</a>
```

I would like to enter a line break into the text belonging to class "rtsTxt". So for example, the "drop this text below" would still be within the list item but a line below.

I've tried a few things with .contains and .replace but I can't seem to nail the so and so! Any lunchtime help, greatly appreciated.

The jsfiddle can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ricardodeano/gFwFR/8/)

Comment: What conjuction points has your demo with the Question? What should be the *pointer* that indicates that the text should go to new line?

Comment: What's the goal ? Why not simply put something like `.rtsTxt {display:block;max-width: 350px;}` in CSS ?

Comment: Hello Roko - the pointer is word of someone's choosing - in the example you would say it was "drop" but it literally could be anything (usually depending upon someone's mood that day!)

Comment: Hello dystroy, yes that would work in most instances but as I've mentioned above, the word/pointer they wish to place the <br/> could be anything.

Comment: @RicardoDeano why than, instead of puttin special words they just don't hit `ENTER` or `SHIFT+ENTER`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.rtsTxt').html(function(_,htm){
  return htm.split(',').join("</br>");
});
```

Demo `---->` http://jsfiddle.net/gFwFR/9/

Comment: `Hi, this is my rtsTxt, hope you like it.`

Comment: and also `</br>` should be `<br>` or either `<br/>` or `<br />`, just not `</br>` :) otherwise that's the answer, just replace `','` with `'drop'` (toLowerCase possibly) (read OP's comment)